# Getting same patch from two different people at the same time

Tags: kernel, open-source

What happens when two different people fixed and send the same patch at the same time?

Comment: Maintainer will apply one of them, if they are identical. Or merge them. This happens a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that both works completely and both send at the send time, still coding varies from a programmer to another.

- The more optimized code will applied.
- Programmer reputation also helps
- previous works done the programmars
- How much each code will be dynamic to later changes

you can find many criteria that affect the chose.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to @ThomasW comment, if it happens that two patches are identical and other criteria the same (which is generally considered rare, I think):

> If that is the case then there's no rules for which to use or not, and
>   you can credit both contributors for the same patch.

Comment: This excludes the case in which the patches are identical.  If that is the case then there's no rules for which to use or not, and you can credit both contributors for the same patch.

Comment: @ThomasW. but would that be possible to have all criteria the same for both? I duobt

Comment: As the primary NGINX packager for Ubuntu (so merges, SRUs, etc. but not security uploads though I do provide debdiffs to the security team for them) a patch to fix a minor issue that was major enough to warrant an SRU from me and someone else was identical.  Because I'm not really egotistical (my girlfriend would say otherwise though), I credited the patch to the other submitter.  The patches were otherwise identical.  So yes there can be some patches which are identical in all ways.  With more complex patches it's rare but it can happen with less complex ones.

Comment: Maybe this would be possible, thanks anyway, ill update my answer